# Adding to List on For Loop (What do I set the List to initially?)

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is a beginner question.

I am going to have a dictionaries with varying amounts of values in their lists.

```
dict1 = {'a': [0,1,2], 'b': [3,4,5]}
dict2 = {'a': [0,1,2,3], 'b': [4,5,6,7]}
```

For each dict, the number of items in the lists is the same.

```
LEN(dict1['a']) == LEN(dict1['b'])
LEN(dict1['a']) != LEN(dict2['b'])
```

With that out of the way, here is my problem. I am trying to add the values in the dictionaries together.

`dict1` should equal `[3,5,7]`

`dict2` should equal `[4,6,8,10]`

My code so far is like this:

```
for x in dict1:
    results = [dict1[x][i] + results[i] for i in range(len(dict1[x]))]
```

The problem that I have is with `results[i]`. Do I create this list before my for clause?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `map` with `operator.add`:

```
>>> from operator import add
>>> map(add,*dict1.values())
[3, 5, 7]
>>> map(add,*dict2.values())
[4, 6, 8, 10]
```

or [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) with a `list comprehension` if you don't want to **import** anything:

```
>>> [sum(x) for x in zip(*dict1.values())]
[3, 5, 7]
>>> [sum(x) for x in zip(*dict2.values())]
[4, 6, 8, 10]
```

**Update:**

```
def func(dic, *keys):
    return [sum(x) for x in zip(*(dic[k] for k in keys))]

>>> dict1 = {'a': [0,1,2], 'b': [3,4,5], 'c':[6,7,8]}
>>> func(dict1,'a')
[0, 1, 2]
>>> func(dict1,'a','b')
[3, 5, 7]
>>> func(dict1,'b','c')
[9, 11, 13]
>>> func(dict1,'b','c','a')
[9, 12, 15]
```

Comment: This is actually for a homework assignment, so I can't import anything.

Comment: @Neil I've added another solution, which uses no imports. :)

Comment: I am getting this: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'itervalues'. I am using Python 3.3.2 by the way.

Comment: @Neil looks like you're using py3.x, solution updated. Now it'll work on both py2.x and 3.x.

Comment: Is there a way to do this conditionally? For example if I had a, b, and c in my dictionary and only wanted to find the sum of a and b? My function is taking two parameters. One of which would be dict1 and the other would be what keys to grab from it and aggregate.

Comment: Thank you very much. My homework was to find the average voting records of democratic senators, and with your help I was able to do it in one line.

Comment: @downvoter care to explain your downvote so that I can improve my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use `zip`: [Python 2](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) and [Python 3](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip)

```
>>> dict1 = {'a': [0,1,2], 'b': [3,4,5]}
>>> dict2 = {'a': [0,1,2,3], 'b': [4,5,6,7]}

>>> zip(dict1['a'], dict1['b'])
[(0, 3), (1, 4), (2, 5)]

>>> [x+y for (x,y) in zip(dict1['a'], dict1['b'])]
[3, 5, 7]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> list(map(sum, zip(*dict1.values()))) #py3.x
[3, 5, 7]
>>> 
>>> map(sum, zip(*dict2.values())) #py2.x
[4, 6, 8, 10]
>>>
```